# Xcode NIB files to support from iOS 6 to iOS8

Tags: xcode, ios6, autolayout, ios8, nib

Since auto-layout will disable the DELTA 6/7 features that can adjust iOS 6 layout issue, what can I do to support iOS6 iOS7 iOS8 with single NIB file? Or I need to create another NIB file (disable auto-layout) to load only for iOS6?

Answer (score 0):

ios 6 supports autolayout. To deal with delta I created parentView which I extend then in every class and put such code, and I am able to support minimum ios 6 even with ios 8.

`- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if(([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"7.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)){

        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
            self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`
    }
}